# Can I make chicken pot pie with mashed potatoes inside?

Tags: chicken

I want to make a homemade chicken pot pie but I would like to top it with mashed potatoes and then put a regular crust on top of that can that be done what would be the cooking temperature or time difference if any

Answer (score 3):

Generally such a concoction (topped with mashed potatoes) is called a Shepherds Pie, but adding a crust... I have no idea what to call that ;-)

When cooking a pot pie everything is already cooked prior to putting it in the baking dish, *except the crust.*

So all you really need to do is make sure your crust is cooked to your desired done-ness. The mashed potatoes might keep the bottom of the crust a little wetter but really it should not require much more than you usually would bake it for, if any. It depends on how hot you bake your pot-pies.

I usually cook them at 425F so I get a nice brown on my crust and it is about 15 - 20 minutes, but that will depend on your crust recipe. I would follow the crust recipe baking instructions and add maybe 5 minutes.

You can then try the pot pie and adjust the backing duration according to your personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

If the ingredients of the pie touch the bottom of the crust, you don't have a vent hole (to allow the steam to escape) and the heat isn't sufficient to bake through the pastry, you will end up with a very soggy, tough crust.

I would ensure all the ingredients have cooled down before assembling the pie, and ensure there is some gap between the mash and the pastry, ensuring there is a vent in the crust and bake accordingly to the package instructions (if shop bought), or as normal until golden and the pie filling is heated through.

A better result might be achieved using cooked, sliced, potatoes on top of the filling rather than mash though.